# Easy, automated, efficient testing methods/environments for Codeigniter and/or CakePHP?

Tags: testing, cakephp, codeigniter, symfony1

I've been playing with Symfony's [testing methods](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/09). They give you the results in the command line (for instance, green text is for OK and red text is for NOT OK). It also tells you the cause of the error.

Is there something similar to this in CodeIgniter and CakePHP?

Comment: Just FYI Lime ( http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/tools/lime ) is a standalone testing suite you could graft into CI or Cake if you wanted. However, i think the coloring is actually a feature of the Symfony Command infrastructure, not the test suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best tool out there that I've seen for codeigniter is a library for [SimpleTest](http://www.simpletest.org/) see http://codeigniter.com/wiki/SimpleTester_-_Unit_testing_library/

Answer (score 1):

With cakephp, you can use e.g. simpletest as a plugin (installation a download/renaming). In fact all the cake-core tests work with it. In cake, once you have written the tests, you can run them in a one-click manner via your browser (yes, you get your green bars, too :-) ). 
If I remember correctly, you can run the tests from the shell, too. If not you can create your own cake-shell as it is easy to extend.